# How can I trigger a file download right from an Android WebView so an authenticated user doesn't have to login a second time?

Tags: android-intent, download, android-webview

The user logs into a mobile page inside my application via the WebView. I am using the following code to capture downloadable resources from a WebView request and pass it off as an intent:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
              startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

In the emulator, this actually opens the Android browser, **then asks the user to login again**, at which point it then starts downloading the file.

Is there a way I can instead trigger the download right from my WebView so the user will not have to login a second time? By default, without adding this DownloadListener, nothing happens at all.

Ideally, once the file is downloaded, I'd like to fire an intent on the file, so if the user has a PDF viewer it will switch to it right away.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue by implementing download listener and pass cookies:

```
this.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long len) {
            if ( null != url && (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".pptx"))) {
                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                int lastSEP = url.lastIndexOf("//");
                String DL_to_filename = url.substring( lastSEP+1 );
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                request.setDescription("requested " + url +" downloading");
                request.setTitle(DL_to_filename);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DL_to_filename);
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                request.setMimeType(mimetype);

                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);                   

                manager.enqueue(request);
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if url is with authentication how can i downlod

Answer (score 0):

The answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/5680028/jihshin worked for me very well But my url did not contain.pdf even after being a pdf so I just removed the if statement and everything went perfect.

```
this.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                long len) {

            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            int lastSEP = url.lastIndexOf("//");
            String DL_to_filename = url.substring( lastSEP+1 );
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            request.setDescription("requested " + url +" downloading");
            request.setTitle(DL_to_filename);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DL_to_filename);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);                   

            manager.enqueue(request);

    }
});
```